# Compiling Ionic App (ios platform) on the cloud

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-native

I got an Ionic app developed, I compiled the android platform very well... But I want to compile the IOS platform too and I haven't Macbook :/ ... Exists any cloud service to compile this platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile iOS app without mac you can:

**OPTION A**

***- Install mac on virtual macchine***

**OPTION B**

Use Ionic **Appflow**

*Appflow is a continuous integration (CI) and continuous deployment (CD) platform for Ionic development teams. Appflow helps development teams continuously build and ship their iOS, Android, and web apps faster than ever.

https://ionicframework.com/appflow

**OPTION C**

Try to use Phone Gap Build. You need to know how it work

https://build.phonegap.com/